# Creating an array of medians. Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble with finding the solution for this exercise:

```
Given scores, an array of integers representing all test and assignment scores, your task is to return an array of integers where output[i] represents the median grade after all marks up to (and including) scores[i] have been entered. Your instructor is a generous marker, so they always round the median up to the nearest integer.

median* - The median of an N-element sequence is defined as follows: If N is odd, the median is the element which stands in the middle of the sequence after it is sorted. If N is even, the median is the average (mean) of the two "middle" elements of the sequence after it is sorted.

Example

•For scores = [100, 20, 50, 70, 45] the output should be medianScores(scores) = [100, 60, 50, 60, 50].

After each score is entered, the median is recalculated as follows:
◦For [100], the median is 100 since it's the only element.
◦For [20, 100], the median is (20 + 100)/2 = 60 since there's an even number of elements.
◦For [20, 50, 100], the median is 50 (middle element).
◦For [20, 50, 70, 100], the median is (50 + 70)/2 = 60(mean of the two middle elements).
◦For [20, 45, 50, 70, 100], the median is 50 again (middle element).


Input / Output
```

I have been trying to get a working code, so far the code works if the length of an array is odd, but if its even it returns an incorrect result;

```
 public static int[] getMedian(int[] arr){

    int[] sortedArr = new int[arr.length];
    int length = arr.length-1;
    int odd = arr.length-1;
    int even = arr.length-1;

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {

        sortedArr[length] = arr[i];
        Arrays.sort(sortedArr);

        if (length % 2 == 0) {
            arr[i] = sortedArr[odd];
            odd--;
        } else {
            arr[i] = (sortedArr[even] + sortedArr[even - 1]) / 2;
            even--;
        }
        length--;
    }
return arr;
```

}

The algorithm works by adding elements from an arr to sortedArr. The elements get sorted and then it checks whether sortedArr is even or odd. If its even, arr[i] becomes the middle element, if its odd, arr[i] is the sum of middle elements divided by 2.

I would appriciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by if the length of the array is even it "breaks" ? I am testing it with even array lengths and the program is not crashing. Do you mean the output is incorrect?

Comment: @djharten Yes, the result is incorrect, i apologize for the bad terminology, i am still new

Comment: You need to divide even and odd by two. Also, sortedArr just has default data in it.

Comment: I would recommend using `Arrays.copyOfRange` to create a sub-array from the original since `sort` will always sort the whole array (including elements not already set (zero)) **or** use the `sort` method that only sorts a range: [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D,int,int)) (but without adding elements at `sortedArr[length]`, use `i` for that) (Obs: `even` and `odd` must be calculated from `i`, the size of the sub-array)

Comment: Sorting an array at each iteration doesn't seem very efficient. Do you have some constraints about efficiency? What is the maximum array size?

Comment: I would also recommend to write a separate method that receives an array and just calculates its median. The main loop would then create a sub-array and call that method (result must be saved in an additional array).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Damien the constrains are arr.length>=1 && arr.length<10^4, i would certanly like to make an algorithm as efficient as possible so i will try all the methods mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non optimized solution.

First a method to just calculate the median of an array:

```java
/** Generous or not: one to round up, zero to round down. */
private static final int generous = 1;

private static int median(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int mid = arr.length / 2;
    if (mid + mid == arr.length) { // little optimized "is it even"
        return (arr[mid-1] + arr[mid] + generous) / 2;
    } else {
        return arr[mid];
    }
}
```

then just call it for each sub-array:

```java
// passed array will be (partially) sorted
private static int[] getMedian(int[] arr) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result[i] = median(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, i+1));
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Bit of optimization: do not create a sub-array, just pass the length to be considered

```java
private static int median(int[] arr, int len) {
    Arrays.sort(arr, 0, len);
    int mid = len / 2;
    if (mid + mid == len) { // little optimized "is it even"
        return (arr[mid-1] + arr[mid] + generous) / 2;
    } else {
        return arr[mid];
    }
}
```

in `getMedian()`, called as

```java
result[i] = median(arr, i+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were overwriting existing values when copying the array to sortedArray.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ret = getMedian(new int[]{100,20,50,70,45});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ret));
    }

    public static int[] getMedian(int[] arr) {

        int[] sortedArr = new int[arr.length];
        int[] retArr = new int[arr.length];
        int len = 1;
        int realLength = arr.length-1;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            sortedArr[realLength-i] = arr[i];
            Arrays.sort(sortedArr);
           // arrays are accessed in reverse so adjust is needed using
           // array length.
            if (len % 2 == 1) {
                // use middle value
                retArr[i] = sortedArr[realLength-len/2];
            } else {
                // average middle values 
                retArr[i] = (sortedArr[realLength-len/2]
                        + sortedArr[realLength-len/2 + 1]) / 2;
            }
            len++;
        }
        return retArr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to improve efficiency, the first step is to determine a better algorithm.

Let us call `median[]` the created array.

I would use two heaps:

- A max-heap `left` for the `k/2` or `k/2+1` lowest values up to the kth index, depending `k` is even or odd.
- A min-heap `right` for the `k/2` highest values up to the kth index

Then,

```
if k is even, median[k] = (left.max() + right.min())/2
if k is odd, median[k] = left.max()
```

Initialisation:

```
left <- min (scores[0], scores[1])
right <- max (scores[0], scores[1])
```

Then, for each new value `x = scores[k]`, you have to manage the two heaps, depending if `k` is even or odd, and depending of the comparisons between `x`, `left.max()` and `right.min()`. It is important that two heaps keep the correct sizes. This implies that sometimes a value will go from one heap to the other.

If `k` even (`k-1` was odd):

```
If x < left.max() then x -> left, left.max() -> right (corresponding value removed from left)
else: x -> right
```

If `k` odd:

```
If x < right.min() then x -> left
else: x -> right, right.min() -> left (corresponding value removed from right)
```

Global complexity: O(nlogn)

I don't know java well. If java doesn't have heaps, I guess you could use `PriorityQueue` instead.